# Export CSV cell content to .txt, with content as file name (R)

Tags: r

I want to export the content of every cell in a column to an individual .txt file with the content of the cell also passed as the filename for the .txt file. I have this script in R below, but for some reason the loop `i in 1:length()` only works for columns, i.e. Column A:Z, but not the rows A1:A26.

Any help to get this script to export the contents of the rows A1:A26 would be appreciated!

Context: This is for creating a MALLET corpus from unstructured text in CSVs for natural language processing.

```
filenames <- names(NLPL)
for (i in 1:length(NLPL)){
  outname <- paste("", filenames[i], ".txt", sep= "")
  write.table(NLPL[[i]], outname, col.names= F, row.names= F, quote= F)
}
```

Comment: Try using `nrow` instead of `length`.

Comment: Thanks @ytk, I tried that before but I get         `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `1:nrow(NLPL)` in the same way as `1:length(NLPL)` or `1:ncol(NLPL)`, but I prefer using `seq_along()`.

For columns, I use `seq_along(NLPL)` and for rows, I use `seq_along(NLPL[,1])`. Maybe someone knows a better way than the `[,1]` to specify we are taking the sequence along a column.

For rows:

```
filenames <- names(NLPL)
for (i in seq_along(NLPL[,1])){
  outname <- paste("", filenames[i], ".txt", sep= "")
  write.table(NLPL[[i]], outname, col.names= F, row.names= F, quote= F)
}
```

For columns:

```
filenames <- names(NLPL)
for (i in seq_along(NLPL)){
  outname <- paste("", filenames[i], ".txt", sep= "")
  write.table(NLPL[[i]], outname, col.names= F, row.names= F, quote= F)
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. `seq_along()` is what the pros use; see e.g. many the R functions in R itself.

Comment: Thanks, I still get `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds` when using `seq_along()` as I did with `nrow()` -- trying to find out more about this error.

Comment: This is a problem within the subsetting inside the for loop. Try just printing i and you will see that it's giving the right indices . Now adjust your code to properly use these indices

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKirchner, solution was pretty simple, just adjust write.table to NLPL[[i,1]]